# Pep8 Python class and method past enter

Tags: python-3.x

who will tell me on pep8 between methods in the class put one enter or 2 enter? preferably a link to the documentation.

```
class Nuub:

    def f(self):
        pass

    def z(self):
        pass
```

Or

```
class Nuub:

    def f(self):
        pass


    def z(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length
Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a **single blank line**.

Also you can try it out in pycharm. I just tried and it is confirmed to be **one enter**.